# connect to pod from outside and from inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service-node-port-range

I created a deployment file which runs some service. The service uses port 7777. I want to access the same service from the outside by typing the address x.x.x.x:7777. I am attaching my deployment file which is currently working properly without service. If I download the Ports part from the Deployment and apply to the service, nothing works. I need to prepare a service file because I will soon connect more additional services that will each use the same IP address but on different ports. What is the best way to work in order to achieve my goal?

It should be noted that the Pod also answers on the same port, therefore I also need access to the outside through the same port both from the inside to the outside and from the outside to the inside on the same port 7777.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: xyz
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        node: w1
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret1
      volumes:
        - name: zzz
          hostPath: 
            path: z/z/z
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: yyy
          hostPath: 
            path: y/y/y
            type: FileOrCreate
        - name: xxx
          hostPath: 
            path: x/x/x
            type: FileOrCreate
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: x
          value: "x"
        - name: y
          value: "y"
        name: quic-image
        image: "xxxyyyzzz"
        name: x-y-z
        volumeMounts: 
          - mountPath: x/x/x
            name: xxx
          - mountPath: y/y/y
            name: yyy
          - mountPath: z/z/z
            name: zzz
        ports:
          - containerPort: 7777
            hostPort: 7777
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 7777
            hostPort: 7777
            protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp
    port: 7777
  - protocol: UDP
    name: udp
    port: 7777
#    targetPort: 7777
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The service is defined as NodePort. You should be able to access the service using the IP of cluster node and the nodeport as given below

CLUSTER_NODE_IP:NODE_PORT